# Not a GROUP BY expression - what should I be aware?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Do you have any ideas why the first code shows error “not a GROUP BY expression” but when I try the second, it does?

I’m thinking it’s about alias but not sure what it is.

1.

```
select 'SNA' as CHANNEL, to_char(BLOCK_DATE,'DD'), count(BLOCK_AMT),
  case when SUBSTR(ACCOUNT_NO,-11,1) in ('1','3','5') then 'Gold' 
       else 'Standard'
  end CARD_TYPE
from "MIS"."V_TRACKING_GNN_3P_SNA" 
where BLOCK_DATE between to_date('09/11/2019','dd/mm/yyyy') 
and to_date('24/11/2019','dd/mm/yyyy')
group by BLOCK_DATE
order by to_char(BLOCK_DATE,'DD');
```

2.

```
SELECT CHANNEL,BLOCK_DATE,CARD_TYPE,COUNT(BLOCK_AMT)
FROM
(
    select 'SNA' as CHANNEL, to_char(BLOCK_DATE,'DD') BLOCK_DATE, BLOCK_AMT, 
    case when SUBSTR(ACCOUNT_NO,-11,1) in ('1','3','5') then 'Gold' 
         else 'Standard'
    end CARD_TYPE
    from "MIS"."V_TRACKING_GNN_3P_SNA"
    where BLOCK_DATE between to_date('09/11/2019','dd/mm/yyyy') 
    and to_date('24/11/2019','dd/mm/yyyy')
)
group by CHANNEL,BLOCK_DATE,CARD_TYPE
order by BLOCK_DATE;
```

Comment: read the rules for aggregation.. definitely 1 and 2 are different

Answer (score 0):

DB tool could be a good teacher.
When you got some error, start again with simple way.
Here is you sql script that easier to understand error.

```
select
    'SNA' as CHANNEL,
    to_char(BLOCK_DATE, 'DD'),
    count(BLOCK_AMT),
    ACCOUNT_NO as CARD_TYPE  // modify this to see easier.
from
    V_TRACKING_GNN_3P_SNA
where
    BLOCK_DATE between to_date('09/11/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('24/11/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
group by
    BLOCK_DATE
order by
    to_char(BLOCK_DATE, 'DD');
```

After run this script, you may understand what you missed.

Answer (score 0):

> Any SELECT expression that is not included in the GROUP function must be listed in the GROUP BY clause

The first option in fixing the error would apply to the following example in which a user tries to execute a SELECT statement:

`SELECT department, class, MAX(number) AS “Highest number of students"  FROM students GROUP BY department;`

> In this example, the error may be corrected by including class in the GROUP BY clause. Class is included in both the SELECT and GROUP BY statements.

`SELECT department, class, MAX(number) AS “Highest number of students” FROM students GROUP BY department, class;`

**In your first query you added only the blockdate in group by clause. So its showing the error**